# Which address are accessed when I use the GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, firewall

I'm faced with a problem when trying to access the GCM from a controlled environment that restrict me to a few websites that I can access. In this environment I need to specify what websites I would get access. At first time, I allow the https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send to free access, but it does not work. Only when I allowed the whole http://google* (notice the asterisc) that worked fine, but I don't can let that mode.

Anybody knows the whole list of websites that are accessed by GCM, in order to register them in my firewall whitelisting?

Answer (score 1):

From the [GCM Http Connection server documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http), it states that:

*`Note: If your organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic to or from the Internet, you need to configure it to allow connectivity with GCM in order for your GCM client apps to receive messages. The ports to open are: 5228, 5229, and 5230. GCM typically only uses 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230. GCM doesn't provide specific IPs, so you should allow your firewall to accept outgoing connections to all IP addresses contained in the IP blocks listed in Google's ASN of 15169.`*

So you need to configure you ports for 5228, 5229, and 5230.